# Jasper report working fine in netbeans but gives exception when deployed as jar application

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm working on my final year project using java swings and jasper reports for reporting.The application including the reports work fine when I run the application in netbeans but when I deploy it to a jar file and then try to execute it using my command prompt I see this huge text of exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationFailedException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getCompiler(JasperCompileManager.java:472)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.loadEvaluator(JasperCompileManager.java:238)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createCalculator(JRFillDataset.java:421)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.(JRBaseFiller.java:428)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:76)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:86)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:56)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:142)
.
.
.
.
....54 more
```

The following function invokes the  jasper report :

```
    public void printReport(String adID){
       try {
            Map parameters = new HashMap();
            InputStream jasperIS =this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Reports/AllHoardings.jasper");
            User connect=new User();
            JasperPrint print=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperIS,parameters,connect.getConnection());
            JasperViewer.viewReport(print,false);
        }catch(JRException je){
            System.out.println(je.toString() +" @ line 2043");
        }catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e.toString());       }
    }
```

[image]

#### Link to the image :

#### The Snap Shot

---

#### The directory listing in netbeans

[image]

#### Link to the image :

#### Project directory listing in netbeans

---

#### Inside my jar file

[image]

#### Link to the image :

#### Inside the jar file

Comment: BTW I'm creating a application using java swings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationFailedException
```

This error suggests to me that NetBeans is solving your issues with Groovy and Jasper Reports in a way that your JAR file is not.  Check to see if there are JARs missing from your JAR manifest that pertain to Groovy.  If yes, add them.

Comment: Ahh !!! thank you ! I added the groovy ----.jar file in the library and it worked :)thanks